# Inline formset returns empty list on save?

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

When I try to save my inline formset it just returns an empty list and no changes are reflected in the database. I have tried doing it with no option and commit=False but they both have the same result. I know there is data because I printed the formset as a table, and I know it is valid because the property is_valid() method returns true. Here is the code:

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = TombstoneForm(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid())
        t = form.save(commit=False)
        t.edit_date = datetime.now()
        t.user_editor = request.user
        t.save()
        print(t)
        formset_construct = inlineformset_factory(Tombstone, Tank, form=TombstoneForm)
        formset = formset_construct(request.POST)
        print("Passed the inline formset")
        print(formset.as_table())
        print(formset.is_valid())
        l = formset.save()
        print(l)
    return render(request, 'main.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I believe I have found the source of my problem and a workaround. The problem was occuring in the BaseModelFormSet class in this method:

```
    def save_existing_objects(self, commit=True):
        self.changed_objects = []
        self.deleted_objects = []
        if not self.initial_forms:
            return []

        saved_instances = []
        forms_to_delete = self.deleted_forms
        for form in self.initial_forms:
            obj = form.instance
            # If the pk is None, it means either:
            # 1. The object is an unexpected empty model, created by invalid
            #    POST data such as an object outside the formset's queryset.
            # 2. The object was already deleted from the database.
            if obj.pk is None:
                continue
            if form in forms_to_delete:
                self.deleted_objects.append(obj)
                self.delete_existing(obj, commit=commit)
            elif form.has_changed():
                self.changed_objects.append((obj, form.changed_data))
                saved_instances.append(self.save_existing(form, obj, commit=commit))
                if not commit:
                    self.saved_forms.append(form)
        return saved_instances
```

The problem was occuring in:

```
if obj.pk is None:
    continue
```

Where it was always hitting continue, so my solution has just been to save the individual form data instead of the formset data:

```
        for form in formset:
            val = form.save(commit=False)
            val.Vessel = t
            val.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

To help out others, where they are having similar problems with formset save returning empty lists, and theres is not much else on SO:

According to the Django docs:

> After calling save(), your model formset will have three new attributes containing the formset’s changes:
>
> models.BaseModelFormSet.changed_objects 
> models.BaseModelFormSet.deleted_objects 
> models.BaseModelFormSet.new_objects

`new_objects` is simply list of new `obj`s, i.e.

```py
[obj1, obj2]
```

`changed_objects`  is a list of tuples, i.e.

```py
[
    (obj1, [list of field names changed]),
    (obj2, [list of field names changed]),
    ...
]
```

I was having a problem where deleted_objects was always `[]`.

First ensure you have the required hidden field in your form:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.id }} # <- have you got this?
    {{ form.DELETE }}
    ...
    {{ form.foo }}
{% endfor %}
```

And secondly, I had the bright idea of disabling all fields when the user the check the delete checkbox. Disabled items are not posted, so then the items to be deleted would not a PK, as OP mentions above if obj.pk is blank, then it would not be added to the (`.deleted_objects` in this case) list . The solution is to rather use readonly, in JavaSript use `.readOnly = true` and in css `:read-only`.