# Django how to save formset with a foreign key?

Tags: python, django

I have two models employee and child(Enfant) related by a foreignkey, like 
models.py

```html
 class Enfant(models.Model) :
     id_emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     id_Enfant=models.IntegerField(blank=True,primary_key=True)
```

views.py

```html
form = EmployeeForm(request.POST or None)
form_EnfantForm_formset =formset_factory(EnfantForm, formset=EnfantFormSet)
if request.method == 'POST'
        if form.is_valid() :
            #pdb.set_trace()
            new_employee=form.save()
            EnfantForm_formset0 = form_EnfantForm_formset.save(commit=False)
            EnfantForm_formset0.employee= new_employee
            EnfantForm_formset0.save()
```

I need to save employee record and enfant records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving a formset returns a list of instances. You have to iterate over this list and assign the field:

```
instances = form_EnfantForm_formset.save(commit=False)
for instance in instances:
    instance.employee = new_employee
    instance.save()
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset

Comment: Thanks – the documentation on this sure is sparse! I also found this answer – had to iterate the individual forms in my formset: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50911510/258794

Comment: I want to point out that this will prevent you from deleting any objects on the formset.  When saving the formset with `save(commit=False)` Django only returns the new and changed objects.  You will need to delete the objects yourself using the `deleted_objects` attribute on the formset.  This is mentioned in the docs linked above.